# How to use count after using group by and count in sql?

Tags: mysql, count

I am trying to see statistics of how many passenger passed from my application. After selecting this query;

```
select count(person_id), person_id from Passenger group by person_id;

count(person_id)    person_id
6                  123
2                  421
1                  542
3                  612
1                  643
2                  876
```

I see that passenger "123" passed 6 times. "421" passed 2 times. "542" passed 1 times etc.. So I want to make analyze and say that;

```
>     1 passenger passed 6 times,
>     2 passenger passed 2 times,
>     2 passenger passed 1 times,
>     1 passenger passed 3 times..
```

Here is [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3fcfa/2) for your better understanding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select cnt, count(person_id)
from
(
  select count(person_id) as cnt, person_id 
  from Passenger 
  group by person_id
) tmp
group by cnt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `SELECT` with a subquery to obtain the result you want:

```
SELECT Concat(COUNT(*), ' passenger passed ', table.theCount, ' times,') FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(person_id) AS theCount, person_id
    FROM Passenger
    GROUP BY person_id
) table
GROUP BY table.theCount
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select count(person_id) as "Num passengers", times
from (
  select count(person_id) as times, person_id
from Passenger 
group by person_id
) sub
group by times order by times ASC
```